# Lambda conversion of method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

If I have:

```
class B
{
    public static boolean test1(File f)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean test2(File f)
    {
        return true;
    }    
}
```

are the following conversions to a full lambda expressions correct?

```
File dir = new File("C:\\TEST");

// here UNBOUND instance method reference
// converted as?  dir.listFiles((File f) -> f.isFile());
dir.listFiles(File::isFile);        

// here static method reference
// converted as? dir.listFiles((File f) -> B.test1(f));
dir.listFiles(B::test1);  

// here BOUND instance method reference
// converted as?  dir.listFiles((File f) -> b.test2(f));
B b = new B();
dir.listFiles(b::test2);
```

then, still, one question:
if I write: `dir.listFiles(B::test2);` I have from the compiler:

```
non-static method test2(File) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

but why is that error not throws for: `dir.listFiles(File::isFile);`

Comment: I think you've got confused: `B::test2` must be an unbound instance method reference to a method in the class `B`, so the lambda argument must be a `B` not a `File`. So you should have got a different compile error telling you that the argument is of the wrong type.

Comment: @Naftalin, thanks, I see the problem!!! However, are the conversions I wrote correct? What do you think about?

Comment: Yes, the conversions all look fine.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, your conversions are correct.

```
public void question() {
    File dir = new File("C:\\TEST");

    // here UNBOUND instance method reference
    dir.listFiles((File f) -> f.isFile());
    dir.listFiles(File::isFile);

    // here static method reference
    dir.listFiles((File f) -> B.test1(f));
    dir.listFiles(B::test1);

    // here BOUND instance method reference
    B b = new B();
    dir.listFiles((File f) -> b.test2(f));
    dir.listFiles(b::test2);
}
```

The compilation problem is because the reference;

```
dir.listFiles(B::test2);
```

or (expanded as a lambda);

```
dir.listFiles((pathname) -> B.test2(pathname));
```

is trying to access `test2` as a static method. It's a *static method reference*. Whereas

```
dir.listFiles(File::isFile);
```

or as a lambda;

```
dir.listFiles((f) -> f.isFile())
```

is an *instance method reference*, it's referring to a (non-static) method on the `File` class.

So although the `File::isFile` looks like a static reference, the use of the *type* in this context is actually referring to an object! Weird huh?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got confused: `B::test2` must be an unbound instance method reference to a method in the class B, so the lambda argument must be a `B` not a `File`. So you should have got a different compile error telling you that the argument is of the wrong type.